# System.UriFormatException occurred in system.dll

Tags: c#, get

I'm making a .net application in visual studio that uses get requests to find information on the runescape wiki. When I try to

```
public string GET(string url)
    {
        WebRequest wrGetURL;
        wrGetURL = WebRequest.Create(url);
        wrGetURL.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
        Stream responseStream;
        responseStream = wrGetURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        string sLine = "";
        int i = 0;
        string response = "";

        while (sLine != null)
        {
            i++;
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
            if (sLine != null)
                response = response + sLine;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

When I run the following code:

```
string response = GET("runescape.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/AsSimpleJson?id=4115");
```

I get the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Does anybody have an idea of what to do about this?

Comment: Can you try full URL as  "http://runescape.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/AsSimpleJson?id=4115" ? with http://

Comment: Try prepending "http:" or "https:" to the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the uri as "http://runescape.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/AsSimpleJson?id=4115" in the GET()